# how to convert IEnumerable<string> to byte[] in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, .net-core

how to convert `IEnumerable<string>` to `byte[]` in c#
is there any option in c#. the `IEnumerable<string>` may contain large data.
After each string new Line is needed

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "convert". If you get the strings "Hello" and "World" from the IEnumerable<string>, how would you expect the resulting byte[]?

Comment: this is *probably* a scenario where it would be better to use a "writer" API; perhaps a `StreamWriter` - then just loop (`foreach`) over the strings, and use `.Write` / `.WriteLine` for each value. But hard to give a concrete example without understanding *what you're trying to do* with this data. What is the *purpose* of the `byte[]` here?

Comment: Reminds me of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59834575) earlier today.

Answer (score 3):

```
IEnumerable<string> myStrings = new[] { "hello", "world"};
var myBytes = myStrings.SelectMany(s => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
```

This will use `UTF8` as encoding for the bytes. You might need to use a different encoding depending on what you want to do with the bytes afterwards.

Note that - as written above - this is not directly reversible because you lose the information where one `string` ends and where the next one starts.

If you want to, you could a `NewLine` (or any other identifier that you could use afterwards to split on) after each string to keep them separate:

```
var myBytes = myStrings.Select(s => s + Environment.NewLine)
                       .SelectMany(s => Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s)).ToArray();
```

For more information on `SelectMany` have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: end of  string is there any wat to add a newline?

Comment: After each string? Or at the very end?

Comment: after each string  is needed

Comment: Some it show 'Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.'  the IEnumerable<string> may contain large data

Comment: @RaZiQPS "after each string is needed": this was not mentioned in your question. Instead of adding requirements in comments, please [edit] your question to make it clear.

Comment: What do you need `myBytes` for after you have created it? It seems that you have too much data so you'll probably need to look at an alternative method.